# SPREADSHEETS: Random item from range that matches criteria

Tags: excel, function, random, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm making a spreadsheet that will (hopefully) select a random item from a given range where that selected item meets a given criteria.

See the table in the example below. I would like it so that the user can input that they want a cheap place to eat in 'Place C'. (This part I can do fine, it's the next part that I would like help with.) *Then I want the spreadsheet to look at this and find a suitable location that meets the needs of the user. Note that in the example there are 3 suitable locations, so I would also like the computer to randomly select one of these.* **So, to finish, I would like a program that finds a suitable location from the list and if there are more than one, it needs to pick one of these at random.**

Thanks.

Also, it has to use just the built-in functions, so no VBA or app scripts.

[image: Example data]

Answer (score 2):

You can add a column D and use =rand() to generate a random number (drag down you can hide this column). Then create a data validation drop down list on E2 to select Cheap, Moderate, or Expensive. Then enter this query in F2:

```
=query(A2:D,"Select B where C = '"& E2 &"' order by D limit 1")
```

This will give you a random pick. Here is a shared example you can copy and try.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/189zTNh-c2hotmpUvVSM_UyeVxIfFsM_bs2lZBBSx6ts/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Great. If that works for you could you please approve the answer. Thanks.